# How do I go to a next storyboard after an IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboardsegue, ibaction

When I use CTRL+Click on next view it don't use the IBAction but goes straight to the next view.

How can I make the app use the IBAction first and then go to the next view.

The IBAction add data to the database, in the next screen I want to add some more data, I know how that works but can't go to the next screen and add the data...

Sorry for the messy description but hope you understand

Comment: next storyboard or next view or scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to do something on button-click, then perform a segue.

1. Make a general segue from your viewcontroller, not from the button.
2. Connect IBAction like normal.
3. In your IBAction method - use self.performSegueWithIdentifier("MyIdentifier")

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding if you can go to next view on button action using below code..

First go to Identity Inspector --> give Storyboard ID to Next View that you want to go..

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyBoardIdentifier"] animated:YES];
}
```

Hope it helps you..